Angular ControlValueAccessor component with input files returns always null value instead of File reference
I'm creating a custom input image upload in Angular using ControlValueAccessor. I wanna integrate it with reactive forms. When I select/change image I wanna the new cutom input to return the file reference but it always returns null.
My custom input component:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-input',
  templateUrl: './image-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image-input.component.scss'],
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: ImageInputComponent,
    multi: true,
  }]
})
export class ImageInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  onChange?: (value: File) => void;
  onTouched?: () => void;
  isDisabled: boolean = false;

  value!: File;

  writeValue(obj: File): void {
    this.value = obj;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
  }

  onPhotoChange(e: any) {
    this.value = e.target.files[0];

    this.onTouched?.();
    this.onChange?.(this.value);
    console.log('photo change', this.value)
  }

}

My templates:
<!-- custom input component template -->
<div class="image-input-container">
  <label for="image-input" class="image-label" *ngIf="!isDisabled"></label>
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="image-input" [disabled]="isDisabled" (change)="onPhotoChange($event)">
  <mat-icon id="mat-icon" fontIcon="edit"></mat-icon>
</div>

<!-- form that contains the custom input field component -->
<form [formGroup]="skillForm!" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
     <div class="image-container">
         <app-image-input formControlName="skillImage"></app-image-input>
     </div>
     <!-- ecc... -->
</form>

When I submit the form i execute this line of code: console.log('SKILL UPDATED', this.skillForm?.getRawValue()); but I get always null in skillImage form field
see the console
I wanna find a solution in order to make my custom input field returns the file reference
